# Update object based on id, error 'this.props.update' is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When passing the function `update` to the`todo` component to the `onSave` function. I save the form. I call the function `onSave`. Get error: `this.props.update` is not a function.

When I click save, it automatically refreshes the page.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {

            todos: [{
                id: 1,
                date: '2019-12-09',
                description: 'Hello'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                date: '2019-11-10',
                description: 'World'
            }],
            isEditing: false,
            id
        };
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }

    update(id, time) {
        this.setState({
            todos: this.state.todos.map(el => (el.id === id ? Object.assign({}, el, {
                time
            }) : el))
        });

        setEditing = (id) => {
            this.setState({
                isEditing: !this.state.isEditing,
                id: id
            })
        }

        render() {
            return ( < div >
                < ul > {
                    this.state.todos
                        .map((todo, index) =>
                            < Todo key = {
                                todo.id
                            }
                            index = {
                                index
                            }
                            todo = {
                                todo
                            }
                            setEditing = {
                                this.setEditing
                            }
                            update = {
                                this.update
                            }
                            />
                        )
                } < /ul> < /div>
            );
        }
    }

    * * Todo * *

        class Todo extends Component {

            state = {
                startDate: new Date(),
                description: '',
            }

            handleChange = (date) => {
                this.setState({
                    startDate: date
                });
            }

            handleDescription = (evt) => {
                this.setState({
                    description: evt.target.value
                })
            }

            saveEdit = () => {
                const {
                    description, status
                } = this.state;

                this.props.update(this.props.id, {
                    description,
                    status,
                    date: this.state.date
                })
            }

            onSave = () => {

                const {
                    description
                } = this.state;

                this.props.update(this.props.id, {
                    description, date: this.formatDate()
                });

                this.setState({
                    isEditing: false
                })
            }

            componentDidMount = () => {
                const {
                    todo
                } = this.props;

                this.setState({
                    description: todo.description,
                    startDate: new Date(todo.date)
                })
            }

            render() {

                return ( < div > {
                        this.state.isEditing

                            ? ( < EditForm handleChange = {
                                this.handleChange
                            }
                            description = {
                                this.state.description
                            }
                            startDate = {
                                this.state.startDate
                            }
                            handleDescription = {
                                this.handleDescription
                            }
                            onSave = {
                                this.onSave
                            }
                            onCancel = {
                                this.onCancel
                            }
                            />): ( < li >
                                < div > {
                                    this.props.todo.date
                                } < /div> < div > {
                                    this.props.todo.description
                                } < /div> < button onClick = {
                                    this.setEditing(this.props.todo.id)
                                } > Edit < /button> < /li>
                            )

                        } < /div>
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the update function in the constructor of the parent in order to work in in the children as a reference to the parent function, example:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      todos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          date: '2019-12-09',
          description: 'Hello'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          date: '2019-11-10',
          description: 'World'
        }
      ],
      isEditing: false,
      id
    };
   //this line right here is the difference
   this.update = this.update.bind(this)

  }
//blablabla
}
```

Then when you will execute this.props.update() in the children, the function that will be executed is the one in the parent, mutating the parent state.

Comment: @Umbro you need to bind it in the parent constructor, and then pass it as a prop as <Todo update={this.update} />

Comment: @Umbro try to declare the function as:  update(id, time){ blabla }  instead of  update = (id, time) => {blabla}

Comment: Well then, try to log what props are send in the child, when you mount the component with console.log(this.props) and check what update prop is @Umbro. But the answer is right, to pass the function to the children you need to bind it to the parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195623/discussion-between-umbro-and-josep-vidal).

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the update method with the arrow syntax (`update = () => {}`).

It means that the context will always stays the one where the function is declared.

If you want the context where it applies to change you need to use the standard syntax

```
function update () {
  ...
}
```

or in a class it is possible to declare it like so :

```
update () {
  ...
}
```

Using the standard syntax you can choose to bind the context where you want the function to be applied like so :

```
this.update = this.update.bind(this);
```

Comment: Click save;  automatic refreshpage

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure to understand what you mean

Comment: I know. I did it. But I have a problem. When I click save form. My page is automatic refresh

Comment: Is it trigerring a submit event ?

Answer (score 0):

Your handler you pass into `EditForm` needs to be bound to `this` in order for you to reference the current component in your handler.

In your handler, `this` is currently likely to be the component that is triggering the event.

Try:

```
this.onSave.bind(this)
```

You can even do this in the ctor as a one time operation:

```
this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);
```

Comment: I put it in constructor in component 'Todo' but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<Todo
     key={todo.id}
     index={index}
     todo={todo}
     setEditing={this.setEditing}
     update={() => this.update()}
/>
```